# How to load images from resources with GetManifestResourceStream?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

How to load images from Resources, please? Some of my images are located inside a folder.

My image is saved as Resource (cf. **Build Action**). I don't use a .resx file.

I'm able to retrieve the list of all my resources with the help of this function:

```
public static string[] GetResourceNames()
{
    var asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    string resName = asm.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
    using (var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resName))
    using (var reader = new System.Resources.ResourceReader(stream))
    {
        return reader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(entry => (string)entry.Key).ToArray();
    }
}
```

but I'm not able to load the resource (an image in my case).

Here are my tests:

```
string[] resourceNames = GetResourceNames();

Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string projectName = assembly.GetName().Name;

string gresourceName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
//string gresourceName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".Properties.Resources";
var rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(gresourceName, typeof(Resources).Assembly);

var list = resourceNames.OrderBy(q => q).ToList(); //sort

//get all png images
foreach (string resourceName in list)
{
    if (resourceName.EndsWith(".png"))
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(resourceName.ToString());

            //var test =  (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(resourceName);

            Stream imageStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(gresourceName + "." + resourceName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

In my case:
assembly = "VisualStudioTest"
resourceName = "testImages/add_32x32.png"

I've tried all combinations without success.
By example:
**assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("VisualStudioTest.Properties.Resources.testImages.add_32x32.png")
assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("VisualStudioTest.g.resources.testImages.add_32x32.png")**

Comment: So, how are the images added to your test assembly?

Comment: In Properties, I choose "Resource" in Advanced>BuildAction.

Comment: If I choose Embedded Resource, I can see the file when I call assembly.GetManifestResourceNames() but I don't understand why I'm not able to load "Embedded" resources (I see their names in my resourcesNames string list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Build actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022) page, `Resource` Build Type is for WPF projects. Are you working on a WPF project?

Using Embedded Resources instead would look like this:

```cs
var asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
foreach (string resourceName in asm.GetManifestResourceNames())
{
    if (resourceName.EndsWith(".png"))
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(resourceName.ToString());
            Stream imageStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The Build Type must be "Embedded Resource". However, I don't understand why I was able to retrieve the list of "Resource" (but not able to load them).

Answer (score 1):

One trick I use in my own code is to query the resource names to match the short file name I'm looking for (e.g. "add_32x32.png") and just use that fully qualified name to pull the image.

```
private Image fromResource(string shortFileName)
{
    var asm = GetType().Assembly;
    var resource =
        asm
        .GetManifestResourceNames()
        .First(_ => _.Contains(shortFileName));
    using (var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
    {
        return new Bitmap(stream);
    }
}
```